# How to add Google Tag Manager snippet in a Quarto website?

Tags: google-tag-manager, quarto

Basically, I cannot find how to add GTM snippet to a Quarto website. Actually, what I need is to be able to add a piece of code inside the `<head>` tag and also another one just after the `<body>` tag.

In Quarto documentation (see [this link](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/projects/websites.html)) I see only instructions to add Google Analytics (which is working already on my website. But now I want to add Google Tag Manager.

Thanks in advance.
Wlademir.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found the solution. I just needed to add the following commands in the .yml file:

```
format:
  html:
    include-in-header: gtm_code_head.html
    include-before-body: gtm_code_body.html
```